# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing an test in Jasmine for my angular 4 component and getting an error "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" . Where and how do I initialize the property ? I initially thought of changing `[(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"` to `[ngModel]="fedExTax?.value"` but I need the two way binding. Could someone suggest me a solution

You could see `[(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"` in html code below

html code

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">
        <label class="col-form-label">{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey|uppercase|translate}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" [readonly]="isReadOnly" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="fedExTax.value"  name="{{FedExciseKey}}" numberFormat="numberPercent:.0-2" (ngModelChange)="change()" [required]="true" tooltip="{{'CAPTIVES.LINES.INCCAPTIVEEXPENSE.' + FedExciseKey + 'TOOLTIP'|uppercase|translate}}"
            placement="bottom">
          <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My test code

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateFakeLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UniqueIdPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit/src/pipes/unique-id.pipe';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent  } from './incremental-captive-expenses.component';
import { createIncrementalExpenses, createFedExciseExpenses } from '../../../../../../test/models';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

describe('IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent', () => {
  let harness: HostFormTestComponent;
  let sut: IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostFormTestComponent>;
  const IncrementalExpenses = createIncrementalExpenses();
  const fedExciseTaxExpenses = createFedExciseExpenses();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
        })
      ],
      declarations: [ HostFormTestComponent, IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent, UniqueIdPipe ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });

    TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
          entryComponents: [IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent],
      }
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostFormTestComponent);
    harness = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    sut = harness.componentUnderTest;
    harness.incrementalExpensesInputs = IncrementalExpenses;
    harness.fedExciseExpensesInputs = fedExciseTaxExpenses;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

   fit('should set fields correctly when the form is displayed', () => {
    expect(JSON.stringify(sut.managerFees)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(IncrementalExpenses.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === 'mgmgtFee')));
    expect(JSON.stringify(sut.actuaryFees)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(IncrementalExpenses.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === 'actuaryFee')));
    expect(JSON.stringify(sut.auditorFees)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(IncrementalExpenses.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === 'auditFee')));
  });

  @Component({
    template: `
    <form #pageForm="ngForm">
      <incremental-captive-expenses *ngIf="incrementalExpensesInputs"
      [(incrementalExpensesInputs)]="incrementalExpensesInputs"
      [(fedExciseExpensesInputs)]="fedExciseExpensesInputs"
      [currentSelectedCurrency]="currentSelectedCurrency"
      [currentSelected953D]= "currentSelected953D"
      (isValid)="incrementalExpensesValid($event)"></incremental-captive-expenses>
    </form>
    `
  })
  class HostFormTestComponent {
    @ViewChild(IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent)
    public componentUnderTest: IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent;
    public incrementalExpensesInputs = createIncrementalExpenses();
    public fedExciseExpensesInputs = createFedExciseExpenses();
    public currentSelectedCurrency = 'USD';
    public currentSelected953D = 0;

    constructor() {
    }

    incrementalExpensesValid(valid) {

    }
  }
});
```

Component code

```
import { Component, SimpleChanges, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, Output, ViewChild, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, NgModelGroup, ControlContainer, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Base } from '@wtw/toolkit';
import * as BackendDto from '../../../../../api/dtos';

const ManagerFeesFieldKey = 'mgmgtFee';
const ActuaryFeesFieldKey = 'actuaryFee';
const AuditorFeesFieldKey = 'auditFee';
const FedExTaxFieldKey = 'fedExciseTax';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'incremental-captive-expenses',
  templateUrl: './incremental-captive-expenses.component.html',
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useFactory: Base.DynamicFormFactory, deps: [IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent] }]
})

export class IncrementalCaptiveAssumptionsComponent extends Base.DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() incrementalExpensesInputs: Array<BackendDto.IncrementalExpense>;
  @Input() fedExciseExpensesInputs: Array<BackendDto.FedExciseExpense>;
  @Input() currentSelectedCurrency: string;
  @Input() currentSelectedCoveragePolicy: number;
  @Input() currentSelected953D: number;
  @Input() show: boolean;
  @Output() isValid = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  public FieldCategory = BackendDto.DynamicFieldCategory;
  public FedExciseKey = FedExTaxFieldKey;
  public isReadOnly = false;
  private _fedExTax: BackendDto.FedExciseExpense = { value: 0, coveragePolicyTypeId: null, is953D: null };
  @ViewChild('incrementalExpensesGroup') private incrementalExpensesGroup: NgModelGroup;

  constructor(form: NgForm) {
    super(form);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.show && changes.show.currentValue) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.markFormGroupTouched(<FormGroup>this.formDirective.controls[this.incrementalExpensesGroup.name]);
      }, 1);

      this.emitFormValidity();
    }
  }

  change() {
    this.emitFormValidity();
  }

  emitFormValidity() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isValid.emit(this.incrementalExpensesGroup.valid);
    }, 1);
  }

  get managerFees(): BackendDto.IncrementalExpense {
    return this.incrementalExpensesInputs.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === ManagerFeesFieldKey);
  }

  get actuaryFees(): BackendDto.IncrementalExpense {
    return this.incrementalExpensesInputs.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === ActuaryFeesFieldKey);
  }

  get auditorFees(): BackendDto.IncrementalExpense {
    return this.incrementalExpensesInputs.find(x => x.fieldInfo.key === AuditorFeesFieldKey);
  }

  get fedExTax(): BackendDto.FedExciseExpense {
    if (this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy !== 0) {
      this.isReadOnly = false;
      return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs.find(x => x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
    } else {
      this.isReadOnly = true;
      return this._fedExTax;
    }
  }

  private markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    if (formGroup && formGroup.controls) {
      Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
        const control = formGroup.controls[key];
        if (control) {
          control.markAsTouched();
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

models.ts

```
export const createFedExciseExpenses = (): Array<BackendDto.FedExciseExpense> => {
    return [
        {is953D : 1, coveragePolicyTypeId : 1, value : 0},
        {is953D : 0, coveragePolicyTypeId : 1, value : 1},
        {is953D : 0, coveragePolicyTypeId : 2, value : 4},
        {is953D : 1, coveragePolicyTypeId : 2, value : 0}
    ];
};
```

Comment: I have added this condition in the div  <div *ngIf="fedExTax != undefined" class="col-lg-3 col-6 mb-3">. and seems to work fine. Is this alright ?

Comment: That's a question for you...if you want to hide the fedExTax section if there is none, then this is a fine solution. But is this behaving the way you expect?

Comment: I am not seeing any situation when it is hidden when I run the application. I mean its always defined when the solution is running. Its only when executing the tests does that error arise if the check is not in place

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not setting up your mocks correctly. In production, you say that the `fedEx` property always defined, but it is not so during testing.

This implies that the the getter is returning undefined. Most likely it is this line:

```
return this.fedExciseExpensesInputs
  .find(x => 
    x.coveragePolicyTypeId === this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy && 
    x.is953D === this.currentSelected953D);
```

Not knowing anything about your code, but knowing quite a bit about unit testing, my first guess would be to check that `this.fedExciseExpensesInputs` is non-empty and contains a value that is returnable by the getter. You don't show where in the code that gets initialized.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have actually shared the complete code of the component as well testcomponent. If you are referring to the test component then in the beforeEach, this in this  particular line the fedExciseExpensesInputs gets initialised. harness.fedExciseExpensesInputs = fedExciseTaxExpenses; . I have also updated the post with the models.ts which returns fedExciseTaxExpenses

Comment: If you referring to the component code then, fedExciseExpensesInputs is an input fed through another component's property and code in the other component is as follows   get fedExciseExpensesInputs(): Array<BackendDto.FedExciseExpense> {
    return this.editableLob.fedExciseExpenses.map(x => {
      return x;
    });
  }

Comment: My assessment is still the same. Somehow your getter is not returning a value. Perhaps `this.currentSelectedCoveragePolicy` or `this.currentSelected953D` is not what you expect. Or perhaps your angular `@input`s are not being initialized properly.  I would recommend that you open up your debugger and step through the code in this location. i'm pretty sure the problem will become clear as soon as you do that.